# [PHP]$_Session and $_POST returns null

Tags: php, session

I'm kind of newbie in php and encountered a problem which I have no clue how to fix it.
I am trying to make a simple system, in which after pressing button (yes/no) some values in database are changing. Unfortunately my $_SESSION and $_POST seems to don't cooperate with me and returns null values.
Here's the code(I've deleted lines including passwords and so on):

```
<?php
session_start();
echo get_defined_vars();
echo var_dump($_session);
echo var_dump($_POST);
if(!isset($_SESSION['zalogowany'])) {
    $_SESSION['text'] = 'Nie jesteś zalogowany!';
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
if(isset($_POST['Submit_Yes']))
{
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $database_username, $database_password);
    mysql_select_db($database, $link);
    $sql = 'UPDATE Tickets SET Głosy=Głosy+1 WHERE ID_Ticketu=$id';
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
}
if(isset($_POST['Submit_No'])){
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $database_username, $database_password);
    mysql_select_db($database, $link);
    $sql = 'UPDATE Tickets SET Głosy=Głosy-1 WHERE ID_Ticketu=$id';
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
}
?>
```

EDITED:
FORM code:

```
  <Form Name=single_ticket_form Method="POST" ACTION="ticket_vote.php">
  <?php         
  mysql_select_db($database, $link);
  $sql = "Select * from Tickets WHERE ID_Ticketu=$id";
  $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  echo '<span>Nick:<p class=ticket_result>' . $row['Nazwa'] . '</p></span>';
  echo '<span>Imię i Nazwisko postaci:<p class=ticket_result>' . $row['Imię_Nazwisko'] . '</p></span>';
  echo '<span>Dział:<p class=ticket_result>' . $row['Dział'] . '</p></span>';
  echo '<span>Treść:<p class=ticket_result_msg>' . $row['Treść'] . '</p></span>';
  echo '<INPUT class=button_yes TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit_yes" value="Tak">';
  echo '<INPUT class=button_no TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit_no" value="Nie">';
  $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
  }
  ?>
  </Form>
```

Comment: You don't need an `echo` in front of `var_dump()`.

Comment: Also, we need to see the form

Comment: Where do you *set* these session and post values?

Comment: you need to write $_session in uppercase on line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**INFOS**

- get_defined_vars return @array => '*echo*' => '**var_dump**'
- $_SESSION        return @array => no need extra '*echo*' before '**var_dump**'
- $_POST           return @array => no need extra '*echo*' before '**var_dump**'
- $_session => **$_SESSION**
- In html form, name of your submit is '**Submit_yes**' and in your condition 'isset' you wrote 'Submit_Yes'
- **in your line $sql, you put simple quote instead of double quote, so the variable inside '$id' wasn't interpreted.**

**FORM:**

```
<form name="single_ticket_form" method="POST" action="ticket_vote.php">
<?php
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    mysql_select_db($database, $link) or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Tickets WHERE ID_Ticketu = $_SESSION['id']";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if ($row)
    {
        var_dump($row);
?>
        <span>Nick:<p class="ticket_result"><?php echo $row['Nazwa']; ?></p></span>';
        <span>Imię i Nazwisko postaci:<p class="ticket_result"><?php echo $row['Imię_Nazwisko']; ?></p></span>
        <span>Dział:<p class=ticket_result><?php echo $row['Dział'] ?></p></span>
        <span>Treść:<p class=ticket_result_msg><?php echo $row['Treść'] ?></p></span>
        <input type="submit" class="button_yes" name="Submit_yes" value="Tak" />
        <input type="submit" class="button_no" name="Submit_no" value="Nie" />
<?php
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong id";
    }
?>
</form>
```

**FORM ACTION:**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    var_dump(get_defined_vars());
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    var_dump($_POST);

    if(!isset($_SESSION['zalogowany']))
    {
        $_SESSION['text'] = 'Nie jesteś zalogowany!';
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['Submit_yes']) || isset($_POST['Submit_no']))
    {
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $link = mysql_connect($host, $database_username, $database_password) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($database, $link) or die(mysql_error());
        if (isset($_POST['Submit_yes']))
            $sql = "UPDATE Tickets SET Głosy=Głosy+1 WHERE ID_Ticketu=$id";
        else
            $sql = "UPDATE Tickets SET Głosy=Głosy-1 WHERE ID_Ticketu=$id";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

Comment: After changing lines which you have posted, var_dump($_SESSION) gives me proper values, but still value in database is not changing. Any idea about this?

Comment: Check my edit, in your line $sql ('UPDATE Tickets SET Głosy=Głosy+1 WHERE ID_Ticketu=$id'), you put simple quote instead of double quote, so the variable inside '$id' wasn't interpreted.

Comment: And so I have changed it earlier. I replaced my code with the one you've posted and still column "Głosy" is not changing.

Comment: It can be your charset encoding database (Głosy have a special character >>  ł  <<)

Comment: Thanks anyway for the help :)